# If $a^m_{1}+a^m_{2}+\cdots+a^m_{n}\in\mathbb Z$, show $a_{i}\in\mathbb Z$

Tags: integers, rational-numbers

> Let $a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{n}$ be rational numbers. If for any positive integer $m$
> $$a^m_{1}+a^m_{2}+\cdots+a^m_{n}\in\mathbb Z$$
> show that $a_{i}\in\mathbb Z$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$.

I tried: let $S(m)=a^m_{1}+a^m_{2}+\cdots+a^m_{n}$, then  use [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), I can prove $e_{i}\in\mathbb Z$ where $e_{i}$ is the $i$-th elementary symmetric polynomial, but I can't prove every $a_{i}\in\mathbb Z$. Thanks

Comment: How do you get that the $e_i$ are integer? Don't you get just rationality, because the formula has $ke_k$ in it, and I don't get how the $k$ gets cancelled out?

Comment: Can you demonstrate that $ e_i \in Z?$ Once you prove that, you are done via Vieta's formulas and rational root theorem.

Comment: My solution to the $n=2$ case uses Lifting the Exponent lemma(a slight modification of [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/#solution-to-problem-4)), which doesn't easily generalize. The approach/idea should be similar, but it's hard to nail down the contradiction.

Comment: Seems you, Sarvesh, just repeated the same request of user26857.  That can be confusing to users.  I think it best to merge the two questions.  I happen to think this question and the answers here are just as worthy of preservation.  So I will flag mods to request a merge of the questions.  Thanks for the alerts!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the result to be false and consider a counterexample with $n$  minimal. Let $b$ be the denominator of any $a_i$ and replace all the $a_i$ by $a_ib$. Since at least one $a_ib$ is an integer it can be ignored and so, by minimality of $n$ all the $a_ib$ are integers.

Similarly, we need only consider $b$ to be a prime $p$ say. Let $c_i=a_ip$, then each $c_i$ is coprime to $p$.

Now suppose $p$ is odd and consider just powers $m=(p-1)p^k$. Then each $c_i^m$ is congruent to 1 modulo $p^{k+1}$ and therefore the total sum of the $c_i^m$ is congruent to $n$ modulo $p^{k+1}$. For sufficiently large $k$ this sum cannot be divisible by $p^m$, a contradiction.

The case $p=2$ is handled the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Easily deduced from the following more general result (I'm still trying to find the source):

> Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n\geqslant 1$ be *distinct* rational numbers. Suppose that there are *nonzero real* numbers $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ and a sequence $\{b_m\}$ of integers such that $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(b_m-\sum_{k=1}^n c_k a_k^m\right)=0.$$ Then $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are integers.

The proof I know uses induction on $n$. Denote $r_m=b_m-\sum_{k=1}^n c_k a_k^m$, take arbitrary $1\leqslant\ell\leqslant n$, and let $a_\ell=p/q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Then $$qr_{m+1}-pr_m=(qb_{m+1}-pb_m)-\sum_{k\neq\ell}c_k(qa_k-p)a_k^m$$ tends to $0$ as $m\to\infty$. If $n>1$, this immediately gives the induction step: let $b_m'=qb_{m+1}-pb_m$ and $c_k'=c_k(qa_k-p)$ for $k\neq\ell$ (the latter are nonzero because $a_k$ are distinct); by induction, $a_k$ are integers for $k\neq\ell$, and since $\ell$ is arbitrary, we're done.

Now consider [the induction base] $n(=\ell)=1$. The above reads: $qb_{m+1}-pb_m\to 0$ as $m\to\infty$. Since these are integers, we have $qb_{m+1}-pb_m=0$ for all sufficiently large $m$, and we may also assume that $b_m\neq 0$ for these $m$ (since $a_1\geqslant 1$). Then $q^k b_{m+k}=p^k b_m$ for all $k$, hence $q^k\mid b_m$ for all $k$, which is possible only if $q=1$.